# How to set setAlpha() on one item in a GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, wear-os, alpha-transparency

is it possible to set a single item in a GridView as transparent?

I got a GridView with an ImageAdapter and want to set the item in center without transparency and the others with setAlpha().

```
gridView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

         Log.v("firstVisibleItem", firstVisibleItem+"");
         Log.v("visibleItemCount", visibleItemCount+"");
         Log.v("totalItemCount", totalItemCount+"");                            

    }
}
```

and this should be done in the OnScrollListener.

**EDIT:**

This is my getView in the ImageAdapter class

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) { 
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLabelFor(position);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100,100));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8); //left, top, right, bottom
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

    return imageView;
}

    public ArrayList<View> getListView() {
    return listView;
}
```

and i want to store the imageView in an array and pass it to my main activity.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably approach it this way:

1. Keep a reference to every view inflated in my adapter, in some sort of an array.
2. Control which view (which index in this array) is in the center at a specific moment (based on heights, widths, number of columns, number of rows)
3. Set a proper alpha to all the views in the array apart from the view identified as the one that is in the center (step 2).

Comment: and this should be refreshed on each scroll, is that right?

Comment: not necessarily refreshed. This should be CHECKED on each scroll whether the view in the center has changed (result of step 2 is different than in previous scroll events). If yes -> then refreshed